# How can I Create a EULA popup for OEM Installs?

Tags: oem

Years ago, when I purchased my Dell Inspiron laptop (the one I'm typing this question on right now), it came with Ubuntu 12.04, OEM Installed by Dell.

When it first launched, a EULA popup came up, prompting me to agree with Dell's EULA.

I was wondering: How can I achieve this on my own OEM installations?

Comment: Dell ships additional software not included on the Ubuntu ISO, and therefore also ships a modified image to provide this additional legal requirement they have. Are you shipping additional software which legally requires this?

Comment: This seems more of a programming question: what level of detail are you looking at? Can you already create a GUI app that does the necessary display with print/agree options? What do you want to happen if a user boots in dev mode and disables your popup?

Comment: Oh, OK, I see. Thanks for the info @dobey. I can already create a GUI app, but I don't know how I can, so that it blocks the setup if the user clicks on deny. Also, I didn't even know dev mode actually exists...

Comment: @kerk12, I would like to commend you on this question - one of the highest quality questions I have seen by a new user. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: You would need a business partnership with Canonical, such as Dell has, in order to build such a custom image and be able to use the Ubuntu trademark and call the custom image "Ubuntu." Unless you are building custom proprietary software that you are trying to ship in the image as well, there would be no legal need to do what you are asking. If you are, then you need to talk to Canonical and a lawyer or two about such a contract arrangement.